# Как закрыть процесс через CommandLine

Tags: python, python-2.x

Я хотел написать маленькую программку для друга, которая позволяет закрывать процессы. С первой частью программы я справился, она закрывала все по PID. Настала вторая часть, закрытие по имени и я столкнулся с проблемой. У моего друга нагружается процессор благодаря SVCHOST (netsvcs), я пытаюсь закрыть его по CommandLine, но у меня выходит только ошибка

> TypeError: This object does not support enumeration

Часть кода с ошибкой.

```
    if h == "killname":
    name = raw_input("Enter name of process# ")
    while True:
        wmi=win32com.client.GetObject('winmgmts:')
        for p in wmi.InstancesOf('win32_process'):
            if name in p.Name:
                pid = int(p.Properties_('ProcessId'))
                if name == "svchost":
                    if "netsvcs" in p.Properties_('CommandLine'): 
                        pid = int(p.Properties_('ProcessId'))
                        print p.Properties_('CommandLine')
                killname(pid)
```

Comment: Как раз таки ошибка идет в строке if "netsvcs" in p.Properties_('CommandLine')

Comment: стоит в таких случая полный traceback приводить. Также если информация необходимо для ответа, то нужно её в вопрос помещать, а не в комментариях (под ответом есть кнопка [edit]). Что `print repr(p.Properties_('CommandLine')` показывает? Для переносимого кода, можно `psutil` использовать (и API по-проще).